# C# Update DataGridView after SubmitChanges()

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've got this piece of code to update dataGridView after adding an Item.

```
dbContext.Item.InsertOnSubmit(new Item());
dbContext.SubmitChanges();
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dbContext.Item;
```

It's a great mystery to me why nothing happens when I'm trying to use it more than once...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what your experiencing, I'm going to assume its that the gridview is not showing the new additional item.

Have you tried calling refresh on that gridview?

Comment: I'm starting the app, adding new item -> dataGridView updates, new item is visible. I'm adding next item -> nothing happens, no exception, nothing. Secondly added item is visible after next time app starts. I've tried refresh, endEdit, resetBinding and many, many more so far...